# How can I determine that the current session is a Windows child session?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I want to determine if the current session is a Windows Child Session.
When I call:

```
[DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WTSGetChildSessionId(out uint sessionId);
```

while running inside the child session, it returns false. I tried to get some info using:

```
[DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
public static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(
IntPtr pServer,
int iSessionID,
WTS_INFO_CLASS oInfoClass,
out IntPtr pBuffer,
out uint iBytesReturned);
```

but didn't find anything noteworthy. The name of the session seems to be a random string, in contrast with `system`, `console` and `rdp-tcp#x`, but I don't know if I can count on that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should be `WTSGetChildSessionId(out ulong sessionId);` What is the result of `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` after calling it?

Answer (score 0):

you can also determine if child sessions have been enabled by using the WTSIsChildSessionsEnabled function it can only created with in an existing user's session.